# I'm running ubuntu 16.04, How do I make a hotspot from the same wifi interface?

Tags: 14.04, hot-spot

I'm Using ubuntu 16.04 and I have a usable wifi connection. I would like a way to create a hotspot from the wifi interface as my PC is connected. Also, I know Ap-Hotspot won't work on 16.04. Please help!

Comment: On mobile devices (Android and iOS) it is not possible to use the wifi interface twice, for connection of the device and for hotspot

Comment: As @Zzzach said, you will need a second wireless card (or use a wired connection as your second network interface). Then the instructions are here: https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-adhoc.html

Answer (score 1):

Any single-band wireless device can only either *receive* **or** *transmit* a wireless signal.

Even my dual-band (5Ghz and 2.4Ghz) can only receive or transmit at any time. Even if I am connected to a 2.4Ghz wifi, I cannot create a 5Ghz hotspot from that same device.

The only possible way to create a wireless hotspot is if you have an internet connection via another wireless card or through a wired connection.

TL;DR - It's not possible.

Comment: That's not correct, most today comercial wirless adpters can recieve and transmit at same time, this feature is used by software like "Connectify" or  "Baidu WiFi Hotspot" for share a wifi connection using the same wifi adapter, unfortunately I have not found a way to do the same in Ubuntu